# Does Django generate a DB call on save if values are unchanged?

Tags: django, django-models

So say I have `Klass` as a Django model.

```
k = Klass.objects.get(id=1)

k.attr1 = k.attr1
k.attr2 = k.attr2
...

k.save()
```

Assuming the values are all the same, will Django's ORM generate an SQL call?

(My application is batch processing some models in a delayed job. It sets them all from a CSV, and if they're the same values it just saves, currently. I just want to know if I should spend time working on some hash mechanism or logic to detect if they're the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why didn't you try it in the shell? Use `django.db.connection.queries` to list all the db operations that have been done in that session.

If you do, you'll see that it does indeed generate a db hit. In fact, you don't even need to set any attributes - just calling `save()` on a freshly loaded model instance will do the trick. Django model instances don't have any concept of 'dirtiness'.